# Python user define Functions

Tags: python

I have read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) tutorial for user define python Function.

This tutorial say:

```
def sum( arg1, arg2 ):
   total = arg1 + arg2
   return total;

# Now you can call sum Function
total = sum( 10, 20 );
print "Outside the function : ", total
```

In my case I have this python function:

```
def myf(arg1):
   .................
   some python progress
   ...................
   return out1,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6
```

And finally I have 6 outputs from my main Function

But if I try to call Function like this tutorial:

```
myf = out1(myvar)
```

Then shows all outputs from `out1,out2,out4=3,out4,out5,out6` and not specific where I want.

For example my correct output from my Function is:

`out1=10,out2=30,out3=300,out4=12,out5=47,out6=77`

that `myf = out1(myvar)` shows me :

```
(10,30,300,12,47,77) and not `10` where i want...
```

Any idea how to get only that I need from outputs?

Comment: What you're doing is nothing like what the tutorial is doing.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], including your code in this case, as from a half dozen statements it's pretty difficult to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess you want to do this: `out1,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6 = myf(myvar)`; afterwards you'll have your 6 variables `out1` till `out6` accessible

Comment: @tim that show me `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a tuple of values, and this tuple is being assigned to `myf`.

If you want just the nth value in the tuple, you can refer to it by `myf[n]`.

In your case, you're looking for `myf[0]`.

```
>>> print(myf[0])
10
```

Comment: if i use this ` print(myf[0])` where is my input value for my function ?sorry i am new i try to lern more

Comment: `a=out1=myf(myvar)` `print (a[0]) ` and then work thank you Shiva maybe i need remove some outs from return to main function for better?

Comment: @jessiejes You can assign that value to another variable. `myVal = myf[0]`. Then you can use myVal where you like.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: one more question pls but if i have function with image processing where `def imagepro(inpath,outpath1,outpath2) ......return new_image1,new_image2` where the outpath1,outpath2 is the path for image1,image2 what changes in this code i need to do that ?

Comment: You want to return those images? What kind of files are they? png? You'd have to open it in `rb` mode, get the bitmap and put it inside a 2D list, and then return it.

Comment: is the new images where create my image processing is not neceserry to return ?is .tif

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow... what do you mean?

Comment: my processing where i want to create a gustom function take as input one image(path of image) and create three new images i need to define correct inputs outputs from this function like before but now with images paths

Comment: How can you create a new image?

Comment: is image processing tool that to do just need define the output paths like this `C:\Users\username\Desktop\image1.tif` and `C:\Users\username\Desktop\image2.tif` and if finish correct my processing then create two new images in this path

Comment: If you are creating the images and writing them to the files, you needn't return anything, I think. Honestly it depends on what you want to do. Can't really help you there.

Comment: ok thank you btw i need to return to get in new var and continue my script maybe is better way is to create new question